# Example Numbers with Labels

Tags: numbering, examples

I have, in my `article`, some examples that look like this:

```
\begin{center}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{center}
```

It looks like I want/need it to, and it works. But now I want to numerate those examples (if possible automatically), with a little number to the left, like when using an `\begin{equation}`. Plus, I want a label.

I'm fairly new and superficial in LaTeX, so I'm open for your knowledgable input on this.

Comment: You should just use the `enumerate` environment: `\begin{enumerate} \item Lorem ipsum ... \end{enumerate}`.

Comment: @Werner Not really, because they're not consecutive. Between these examples, there's some explanatory text.

Comment: If you want to stop the `enumerate` environment then write something else then start another `enumerate` environment while continuing from the last number, the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package will do that for you.
`\begin{enumerate}\item First item.\item Second item. \end{enumerate}Text.\begin{enumerate}[resume]\item Third item \end{enumerate}`
It would be great if you posted a MWE.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi I have no idea what an MWE is, sorry.

Comment: @LambdaDusk Welcome to TeX.SX! The example you're presenting doesn't explain *why* you should want such a thing. Perhaps a *real* use case might help to find a way for solving your issue.

Comment: I just want a floating number to the left or right of that block, plus a label...

Comment: MWE = minimum working example, a TeX document that shows what you are trying to do. http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html

Comment: could you post a screen shot or a hand-made image of how you'd like it to look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this is to define a custom environment so that the changes you need to make are minimal.  Below I have defined a `MyQuote` environment which you use instead of the `center` environment and it requires a parameter which defines how you want to label this:

[image]

### Notes:

- As per your comments you had indicated that the labels were non-consecutive, so the method here provides an environment which allows you to individually specify the labels. If you want them to be consecutive you can adapt this to use the `resume` feature available with the `enumerate` environment from [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem) as per Harish Kumar's answer.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{MyQuote}[1]{%
    \begin{description}
    \item [#1]
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{center}
}{%
    \end{center}
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{description}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{MyQuote}{3}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{MyQuote}

\begin{MyQuote}{7}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{MyQuote}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the `\item` appear on the right side?

Answer (score 4):

I think, I have not understood your requirements. But still, giving it a try.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=2cm,rightmargin=2cm,labelsep=1.7cm]
 \item { Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}}\label{item:blur}

\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
 \item { Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}}
\end{enumerate}

From item~\ref{item:blur}, it can be seen that....

\end{document}
```

[image]

The code given in this answer is (may be) called a MWE.

Comment: +1: But you have removed the fact that the OP wanted the text centered.

Comment: @PeterGrill: It was a confusion. But any how, now there is solution (by you) with `centering`. :)

Comment: Yeah, but I was hoping you could figure out how to do it without using a `minipage`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The following provides an "enumeration" that is breakable across the page boundary. The number is set as a `\marginpar` and pushed back into the text block. This may cause some overlapping problems, but I'm not sure whether this is an issue for you (your code snippet didn't show any such usage):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\makeatletter
\reversemarginpar% Switch side of \marginpar
\newenvironment{numquote}[1]{% \begin{numquote}{<num>}
  \par\sbox\z@{\bfseries#1}%
  \leavevmode%
  \marginpar{\rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}\usebox\z@}}%
  \centering%
}{% \end{numquote}
  \par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{numquote}{3}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{numquote}
\lipsum[2-3]
\begin{numquote}{7}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{numquote}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{numquote}{97}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{numquote}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{numquote}{102}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
  \\ \emph{sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt}
  \\ \emph{ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\end{numquote}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text, *Lorem ipsum* style.